# Javascript injection in office 365 site.

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, custom-actions

I am doing a js injection using custom action.

I am loading jquery first and then my custom js. I have applied sequence in custom action 0 for jquery and 100 fro my custom javascript.

My problem is some time jquery not load before my custom javascript so i got error $ is not defined.

I am using jquery CDN.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom js file you can check whether jQuery has loaded or not. If not loaded then you can manually load it and then continue with your script.

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("jQuery.js, null, CustomScriptInit);
}

function CustomScriptInit() {
    //Custom script starts here
}
```